# gRaphael linechart draws values beyond axis

Tags: javascript, linechart, graphael

When drawing a linechart with gRaphael using milliseconds along the x-axis I commonly get inconsistencies in the placement of the data points.  Most commonly the initial data points are to the left of the y-axis (as seen in the fiddle below), sometimes the last data-point will be beyond the right side of the view-box/past the termination of the x-axis.

Does anyone know:
1) Why this occurs,
2) How to prevent it,  &/or
3) How to check for it (I can use transform to move the lines/points if I know when it has happened/by how much).

my code:

```
var r = Raphael("holder"),
txtattr = { font: "12px sans-serif" };
var r2 = Raphael("holder2"),
txtattr2 = { font: "12px sans-serif" };

var x = [], y = [], y2 = [], y3 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    x[i] = i * 10;
    y[i] = (y[i - 1] || 0) + (Math.random() * 7) - 3;
}
var demoX = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],[3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7, 8]];
var demoY = [[12, 32, 23, 15, 17, 27, 22], [10, 20, 30, 25, 15, 28]];

var xVals = [1288885800000, 1289929440000, 1290094500000, 1290439560000, 1300721700000,   1359499228000, 1359499308000, 1359499372000];
var yVals = [80, 76, 70, 74, 74, 78, 77, 72];
var xVals2 = [1288885800000, 1289929440000];
var yVals2 = [80, 76];

var lines = r.linechart(10, 10, 300, 220, xVals, yVals, { nostroke: false, axis: "0 0 1 1", symbol: "circle", smooth: true })
.hoverColumn(function () {
    this.tags = r.set();

    for (var i = 0, ii = this.y.length; i < ii; i++) {
        this.tags.push(r.tag(this.x, this.y[i], this.values[i], 160, 10).insertBefore(this).attr([{ fill: "#fff" }, { fill: this.symbols[i].attr("fill") }]));
        }
    }, function () {
        this.tags && this.tags.remove();
        });

lines.symbols.attr({ r: 3 });


var lines2 = r2.linechart(10, 10, 300, 220, xVals2, yVals2, { nostroke: false, axis: "0 0 1 1", symbol: "circle", smooth: true })
.hoverColumn(function () {
    this.tags = r2.set();

    for (var i = 0, ii = this.y.length; i < ii; i++) {
        this.tags.push(r.tag(this.x, this.y[i], this.values[i], 160, 10).insertBefore(this).attr([{ fill: "#fff" }, { fill: this.symbols[i].attr("fill") }]));
        }
    }, function () {
        this.tags && this.tags.remove();
        });

lines2.symbols.attr({ r: 3 });
```

I do have to use gRaphael and the x-axis has to be in milliseconds (it is labeled later w/customized date strings)

Primary example fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/kcar/aNJxf/

Secondary example fiddle (4th example on page frequently shows both axis errors):
http://jsfiddle.net/kcar/saBnT/

root cause is the snapEnds function (line 718 g.raphael.js), the rounding it does, while fine in some cases, is adding or subtracting years from/to the date in other cases.

Haven't stepped all the way through after this point, but since the datapoints are misplaced every time the rounding gets crazy and not when it doesn't, I'm going to go ahead and assume this is causing issues with calculating the chart columns, also before being sent to snapEnds the values are spot on just to confirm its not just receiving miscalculated data.

code of that function from g.raphael.js

```
snapEnds: function(from, to, steps) {
    var f = from,
        t = to;

    if (f == t) {
        return {from: f, to: t, power: 0};
    }

    function round(a) {
        return Math.abs(a - .5) < .25 ? ~~(a) + .5 : Math.round(a);
    }

    var d = (t - f) / steps,
        r = ~~(d),
        R = r,
        i = 0;

    if (r) {
        while (R) {
            i--;
            R = ~~(d * Math.pow(10, i)) / Math.pow(10, i);
        }

        i ++;
    } else {
        if(d == 0 || !isFinite(d)) {
            i = 1;
        } else {
            while (!r) {
                i = i || 1;
                r = ~~(d * Math.pow(10, i)) / Math.pow(10, i);
                i++;
            }
        }

        i && i--;
    }

    t = round(to * Math.pow(10, i)) / Math.pow(10, i);

    if (t < to) {
        t = round((to + .5) * Math.pow(10, i)) / Math.pow(10, i);
    }

    f = round((from - (i > 0 ? 0 : .5)) * Math.pow(10, i)) / Math.pow(10, i);
    return { from: f, to: t, power: i };
},
```

Comment: These errors are mostly eliminated (they still occur just not nearly as much), if I convert the milliseconds to hours, which is still not ideal in my case, but may work as a quick fix for anyone else having the same issue.

Comment: just to be clear referring to milliseconds/hours from Epoch

Comment: While investigating this, it appears that some times its just the line scale that is off (sometimes the line is too long so the first and last points are beyond where they should be, sometimes the line is too short), sometimes it is just the positioning.  For the life of me I have no idea why the same data/code results in completely different errors.

Comment: I found this answer to be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075013/how-do-you-get-a-y-axis-that-starts-at-zero-in-graphael-if-none-of-your-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

removed the rounding nonsense from snapEnds and no more issues, not noticed any downside from either axis or any other area of the chart.  If you see one I'd love to hear it though.

code of that function from g.raphael.js now:

```
snapEnds: function(from, to, steps) {
     return {from: from, to: to, power: 0};       
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you comment this:

```
        if (valuesy[i].length > width - 2 * gutter) {
            valuesy[i] = shrink(valuesy[i], width - 2 * gutter);
            len = width - 2 * gutter;
        }

        if (valuesx[i] && valuesx[i].length > width - 2 * gutter) {
            valuesx[i] = shrink(valuesx[i], width - 2 * gutter);
        }
```

in g.line.js, It seems to solve the problem, and it also solves a similar problem with the values in the y axis.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, commenting out the body of the snapEnds function from g.raphael.js seems to have done the trick and 3 months afterwards I have not noticed any negative side effects from doing so

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading from v0.50 to v0.51 fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Sadly I was already on 0.51, but I know several different fixes for this issue were suggested on the g.raphael git so I'm guessing the fix is working itself in.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why it occurs, adding in a transparent set was not a desirable option.
The simplest way to check for if the datapoints were rendered outside of the graph seems to be getting a bounding box for the axis set and a bounding box for the datapoints and checking the difference between the x and x2 values.

If anyone can help me with scaling the datapoint set, or figure out how to make this not happen at all, I will still happily appreciate/up vote answers

```
//assuming datapoints  is the Raphael Set for the datapoints, axes is the 
//Raphael Set for the axis, and datalines is the Raphael Set for the 
//datapoint lines
var pointsBBox = datapoints.getBBox();
var axesBBox = axes.getBBox();
var xGapLeft = Math.ceil(axesBBox.x - pointsBBox.x); 
//rounding up to integer to simplify, and the extra boost from y-axis doesn't 
//hurt, <1 is a negligible distance in transform
var xGapRight = Math.ceil(axesBBox.x2 - pointsBBox.x2);
var xGap = 0;
if(xGapLeft > 0){
     datapoints.transform('t' +xGapLeft +',0');
     datalines.transform('t' +xGapLeft +',0');
     xGap = xGapLeft;
}else if (xGapRight < 0) { //using else if because if it is a scale issue it will
//be too far right & too far left, meaning both are true and using transform will
//just shift it right then left and you are worse off than before, using 
//set.transform(scale) works great on dataline but when using on datapoints scales
// symbol radius not placement
     if (xGapLeft < 0 && xGapRight < xGapLeft) { xGapRight = xGapLeft; }  
//in this case the initial point is right of y-axis, the end point is right of 
//x-axis termination, and the difference between last point/axis is greater than
//difference between first point/axis

     datapoints.transform('t' +xGapRight +',0');
     datalines.transform('t' +xGapRight +',0');
     xGap = xGapRight;
}
rehookHoverOverEvent(xGap);  //there are so many ways to do this just leaving it
//here as a call to do so, if you don't the hover tags will be over the original 
//datapoints instead of the new location, at least they were in my case.
```

Comment: I will be honest, I don't really care for this fix because it doesn't address root issue, and doesn't work if the line is just too long or too short (scaling issue), but it is a band aid that is working for me, and may work for someone else, but that is why I did not select it as "accepted answer."